# Exporting to CSV - C#

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I need to export a generic list to CSV.  Obviously I could write my own, but would like to avoid this!

I am able to google and find a lot of CSV parsers, but not many writers.  I have downloaded FileHelpers but it doesn't properly escape output.

For instance if a field is equal to

```
,,",,,
```

the output is simply:

```
,,",,,
```

For the field.  I would expect:

```
",,"",,,"
```

correct?

Any suggestions, or should I just do it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out RFC 4180.  I had to write a XSL to convert XML to CSV and this made it very easy to know what the 'right' thing is to do.

http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Comment: That's all well and good, assuming that the applications generating and consuming the CSV both conform to RFC 4180 in precisely the same way.  In the Real World, CSV is very much like HTML, in that very nearly nobody does it according to the standard, and that Microsoft makes a product that doesn't produce or consume the standard.  With so many of the world's CSV's being created by OLD versions of Excel, the situation is very similar to when IE6 and its broken HTML/CSS interpretation controlled 98.5% of the market.

Comment: Very true Matt, but I would contend that if an app either fully conforms to the RFC or it doesn't and that if you're going to build your own tool, as the OP does, you should strive for perfection and follow the RFC.

Comment: Postel's Law:  Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Postel#Postel.27s_Law

Answer (score 4):

FileHelpers will do what you ask with the [FieldQuoted](http://www.filehelpers.com/attributes.html) attribute on your field in the record mapping class.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the RFC ('If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then double quotes may not appear inside the fields.'), it is wrong in one case: [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)], with a field of 'abc"123' will output 'abc"123'.  But it will catch commas so a field of 'abc,123' will output '"abc,123"'.  That said, I can just make the QuoteMode not optional and quit being pedantic? :)

Comment: FileHelpers may cover cases outside of the RFC, like that one, since there will be cases of CSV files created by developers who have never read the RFC.  You hadn't.  ;-)

Comment: When working on FileHelpers, we have *not* tried to be conformant to any RFC, nor have we ever claimed to be.  What we *have* tried rather extensively to do is ensure compatibility with multiple versions of the extremely quirky Excel/Office CSV format, since that CSV dialect composes such a large percentage of all "Real World" business applications we've had to support for ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

With how simple it is to make your own, I say write you own class for this.  You could handle any nuances on your own pretty easily.

Comment: Yah... reading about the nuances right now.  If it is just commas, quotes, and newlines it might be simple enough.  I was hoping that FileHelpers could be used for both reading and writing -- it would gaurantee that any file written could be read correctly -- but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I can really recommend [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) by Josh Close for reading and writing csv format. CsvHelper will handle most common use cases, including escaping of strings with special characters.

You can use simple methods to read and write (lists of) objects or manually read/write any field you want.